# Web does not exist in current context?

Tags: c#, console-application

just working on a tutorial, and I have a error saying that 'web' does not exist in the current context as I believe I need to make it globally available however not sure how I do this, below is my code:

```
namespace ServerObjectModel
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            using (var site = new SPSite("http://portal.ccrs.lab/wts"))
            {
                SPWeb rootWeb = site.RootWeb;

                using (var web = site.AllWebs["wts"])

                Console.WriteLine(web.Title);

                var lists = web.Lists; //web is underlined as error.

            }
        }
    }
```

Please advise.

Comment: You're missing the braces on your inner `using` statement, so it only applies to the next line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Without curly braces (`{ }`) `web` is visible only in the next line. You should wrap in curly braces:

```
using (var web = site.AllWebs["wts"])
{
    Console.WriteLine(web.Title);
    var lists = web.Lists;

    // some code that uses web
}
```